# How do I update Azure VM Agent, aka "waagent" package for CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, azure, centos, centos7

I followed the guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-update-agent?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Flinux%2Ftoc.json) to update waagent using this command:

```
sudo yum install waagent
```

However my server is unable to find the package. The reason why I want to update the package is because I'm unable to setup backup. Whenever I try, I'll get an error "VM agent is unable to communicate with the Azure Backup Service". Below is the screenshot.

[Azure Operation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BywQW.png)

**Edit**: My virtual machine is not set up in the classic environment.

Comment: Not classic, so I supposed is ARM module. I'll update this info in my question.

Answer (score 2):

On CentOS or RHEL you have to execute

```
sudo yum update WALinuxAgent
```

to update the waagent.

You can check that the update was successful by calling `waagent --version`

Answer (score 0):

I decided to update waagent manually using the guide from the link I provided. After that I'm able to setup and run backups without problem.